# CGContextDrawPDFPage crashes randomly with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on OS X 10.8

Tags: pdf, core-graphics, osx-mountain-lion, exc-bad-access

My application takes a PDF and generate thumbnails for a given number of pages.

**Everything is fine on OS X 10.7**

On OS X 10.8, on some pages, on some PDFs (on 1400 tested the count is 7 documents with a single "offending" page) it fails to render resulting in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling **CGContextDrawPDFPage**

Sometimes (1 over 10) it succeed. But 90% of the time that page on that document causes a crash.

The relevant code, posted below, is repeated in a loop for each **pageNumber** to be rendered of the **pdfDocument** provided. Each iteration produces a **CGImageRef** imgRef that is saved into an array and used later.

---

Suppose crash happens on page 30.

If I render from 28 to 38 is ok.

If I render from 27 to 37 crash.

If I render just 30 is always ok.

Some sets of pages, containing the offending one, crash. Other don't.

---

It seem to be a bug in PDFKit 10.8... (messing things up while trying to do some internal caching optimization when asked to render multiple pages of the same document?)

Of course I can't exclude a bug in my code but it seem very unlikely.

Any idea of how to work this around will be appreciated.

```
    CGPDFPageRef     pdfPage      =   CGPDFDocumentGetPage 
                                            ( pdfDocument,
                                              pageNumber );

    if( !pdfPage ) return;

    CGPDFPageRetain(pdfPage);

    CGRect          rect          =   CGPDFPageGetBoxRect
                                            ( pdfPage,
                                              kCGPDFCropBox);

    CGColorSpaceRef imgColorSpace =   CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB ( );

    CGContextRef    contextRef    =   CGBitmapContextCreate
                                            ( NULL,
                                              (size_t) (rect.size.width),
                                              (size_t) (rect.size.height),
                                              8,
                                              ((size_t) (rect.size.width))*4,
                                              imgColorSpace,
                                              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

    CGColorSpaceRelease ( imgColorSpace );
    if( !contextRef ) return;

    CGContextDrawPDFPage ( contextRef, pdfPage ); // <==== EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    CGImageRef      imgRef        =   CGBitmapContextCreateImage
                                            ( contextRef );

    CFRelease ( contextRef );

    CGPDFPageRelease( pdfPage );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of PDFKit introduced in OS X 10.8

The bug has been fixed in OS X 10.9